# Has anyone had success deploying pyqt to iOS with pyqtdeploy?

Tags: ios, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have been using PyQt for years and would love to be able to use for an iOS app now that both apparently support it. However, I have never had any luck with pyqtdeploy. The tutorial is hard to follow and the build errors difficult to read.

Has anyone had any success with this? Or possibly with another PyQt5 deployment method for iOS?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I installed everything with homebrew: qt5@5.8.0, python3@3.6.0 pyqt5@5.7.1; and pyqtdeploy-1.3.1 installed with pip3. I also tried the pyqtdeploy-1.3.2.dev1612281206 snapshot installed from source. I ran into so many problems that I wasn't interested in getting into troubleshooting a specific problem. The wording of the tutorial is just difficult to follow, it's hard to tell which file he is talking about and in what directory, and where the SYSROOT variable should point, where the qmake symlinks go, etc. There are also lots of build errors for missing files which I was unable to track down, for example "/$SYSROOT/lib/python3.5/_bootlocale.py", or some arc file which I can't pull up right now. It also seems to top out at python3.5 and doesn't work with python3.6 which is all the hombres offers right now. It just seems like such a mess that I would simply ask if anyone has actually had success with it and start from there.

Comment: In what way is the tutorial hard to follow? What build errors are hard to read?

Comment: edited to include more information

Comment: I think you may get a better response by posting on the [pyqt mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt). The question "has anyone had any success with this" seems to be answered by [this thread](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2016-April/037378.html). As for the other points you raise in the edit to your question: the only way the docs are going to get improved is if people such as yourself give specific feedback that the author of pyqtdeploy can act on.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the other thread.

Comment: I've noticed the version numbers are critical with `pyqtdeploy`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll, I'm answering my own question now that I've had some success with pyqtdeploy and iOS. I got to the stage of signing the app but don't have a developer certificate at the moment so it of course failed. I have not yet deployed to the iphone simulator because pyqtdeploy does not prepare the correct architecture when deploying to the iPhone simulator.

As a beginner with pyqtdeploy the tutorial was an inadequate starting point. I had to skip to the chapter about building the sysroot. So I would say this is mostly a documentation issue.

Comment: Any luck with Android?

Comment: Android isn't on my list of supported platforms at this point, sorry.

Comment: Would be interested in any screen shots of pyqt5 running on iOS